# Zillow scraper: Why I can't scrape full listing from Zillow search

Tags: python, web-scraping, zillow

I am trying to explore zillow housing data for analysis. but I found the data I scraped from Zillow would be much less then listing.

there is one exmaple:

I try to pull house-for-sale listing on 35216:
https://www.zillow.com/birmingham-al-35216/?searchQueryState=%7B%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%2235216%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-86.93997505787829%2C%22east%22%3A-86.62926796559313%2C%22south%22%3A33.33562772711966%2C%22north%22%3A33.51819716059094%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A73386%2C%22regionType%22%3A7%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A13%2C%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%7D

we can see there are 76 records. and if I use google chrome extension: Zillow-to-excel , all 76 houses in listing can be scraped.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zillow-to-excel/aecdekdgjlncaadbdiciepplaobhcjgi/related

But when I use Python with request to scrape zillow data, only 18-20 records could be scraped.
here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cnt=0
stop_check=0
ele=[]
url='https://www.zillow.com/birmingham-al-35216/'
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}
for i in range(1,2):
    params = {
    'searchQueryState':'{"pagination":{"currentPage":'+str(i)+'},"usersSearchTerm":"35216","mapBounds":{"west":-86.83314614582643,"east":-86.73781685417354,"south":33.32843303639682,"north":33.511017584543204},"regionSelection":[{"regionId":73386,"regionType":7}],"isMapVisible":true,"filterState":{"sort":{"value":"globalrelevanceex"},"ah":{"value":true}},"isListVisible":true,"mapZoom":13}'
    }
    page=requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=params,timeout=2)
    sp=soup(page.content, 'lxml')
    lst=sp.find_all('address',{'class':'list-card-addr'})
    ele.extend(lst)
    print(i, len(lst))
    if len(lst)==0:
        stop_check+=1
    if stop_check>=3:
        print('stop on three empty')
```

Headers and params comes from web using chrome develop tool. I also tried other search and found I only can scrape first 9-11 records on each pages.

I know there is a zillow API but it could be used for a general search like all houses in a zipcode. So I want to try web-scraping.

May I have some suggestions how to fix my code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm'

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}

houses = []
for page in range(1, 3):
    params = {
        "searchQueryState": json.dumps({
            "pagination": {"currentPage": page},
            "usersSearchTerm": "35216",
            "mapBounds": {
                "west": -86.97413567189196,
                "east": -86.57244804982165,
                "south": 33.346263857015515,
                "north": 33.48754107532057
            },
            "mapZoom": 12,
            "regionSelection": [
                {
                    "regionId": 73386, "regionType": 7
                }
            ],
            "isMapVisible": True,
            "filterState": {
                "isAllHomes": {
                    "value": True
                },
                "sortSelection": {
                    "value": "globalrelevanceex"
                }
            },
            "isListVisible": True
        }),
        "wants": json.dumps(
            {
                "cat1": ["listResults", "mapResults"],
                "cat2": ["total"]
            }
        ),
        "requestId": 3
    }

    # send request
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

    # get json data
    json_data = page.json()

    # loop via data
    for house in json_data['cat1']['searchResults']['listResults']:
        houses.append(house)


# show data
print('Total houses - {}'.format(len(houses)))

# show info in houses
for house in houses:
    if 'brokerName' in house.keys():
        print('{}: {}'.format(house['brokerName'], house['price']))
    else:
        print('No broker: {}'.format(house['price']))
```

```
Total houses - 76
RealtySouth-MB-Crestline: $424,900
eXp Realty, LLC Central: $259,900
ARC Realty Mountain Brook: $849,000
Ray & Poynor Properties: $499,900
Hinge Realty: $1,550,000
...
```

P.S. do not forget to mark answer as correct if I help you :)

Comment: thanks a lot! @t4kq.  May I know if there is any tutorial about detail search query parameter? If so, that would be great!

Comment: Just use devtool to get answer on all your questions)

Comment: Appreciate your help!